# PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile -- local storage questions

Tags: cordova

I'm new to app dev with phone gap, but not to web app development. To date, I've just been doing web apps that run off our corporate servers. I need the apps to be stand alone, so...

I am building a proprietary app for the company I work for. The App will be used by field crews to show their scheduled work orders for the day. Each work order has a bunch of information about the client they are seeing, plus a PDF schematic of the client's system that the crew is servicing. A typical day for a crew can involve anywhere from 5 to 50 work orders.

So far, I have been using a web app I developed which downloads all the information as it's needed. IE: when the user opens the work order, the app sends a request for the client's details from the server. If the user wants to look at the PDF schematic, they have to open it and wait for it to download before viewing. In areas where cell reception is minimal, or non-existant, the user may be left waiting for a long time for the work order details. This can be a big problem.

My question is about storing the information for every work order right on the phone. My research tells me that the HTML5 local storage caps out at 5MB. This very insufficient since, with up to 50 work orders (and thus up to 50 PDF documents) I'm looking at almost 5MB for *each* work order. But I'm also seeing reference to PhoneGap's local database API and I can't quite nail down the details of this API.

I'm wondering if it is possible to store all information about each work order in that PhoneGab database right on the phone's internal storage, including the PDF for each client?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use phone gap to store the PDF's directly on the phone's SD card and then use HTML5 localStorage to store the rest of the data about the work order as well as a reference to where the PDF is on the file system in JSON format.

There are also plugins for phonegap to use the native SQLite databases on the phones if you'd prefer to do that. e.g.

https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-Android

https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-iOS

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid storing the PDFs in the localstorage (or other) database.  Why not use the filetransfer PhoneGap calls to download files and merely reference them in localstorage.  Your files are independent from the database and therefore would work better to reference (and show) them using the inbuilt browser.

Comment: Would the filetransfer that you're referring to only download when the user requests to see the PDF, or would I be able to download all the PDFs in one shot to reference them later?